# Connecting sockets over internet network fails

Tags: .net, sockets

## Table of Contents

- Preface
- Serverside Code
- Clientside Code
- Local Computer Example (*Successfull*)
- İnternet Network Example (*Unsuccessfull*)
- My Possibility considerations

## Preface

I take these codes from MSDN's class library examples. So it must work correctly. Yes, I'm partially right. When running on my computer it succeed. But over internet network, it failes. I'm taking *ConnectionRefused* **SocketErrorCode** each time.
I'll give source code below, initially, you must know my modified tests.

> For Server Code:

- I used *IPAddress.IPv6Any* instead of *IPAddress.Any*.
- Also I tried without *server.AllowNatTraversal(true)*

> But it failed

## Serverside Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace ServerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener server = null;
            try
            {
                int port = 13000;
                server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
                server.AllowNatTraversal(true);
                server.Start();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
                string data = null;
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected: {0}", client.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
                    data = null;
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                    int i;
                    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);
                        data = data.ToUpper();
                        byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);
                    }
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket exception message: {0}", e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Socket Error Code: {0}", e.SocketErrorCode.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                server.Stop();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();            
        }
    }
}
```

## Clientside Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ClientTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started...");
            Console.WriteLine("İP Address:");
            string hostName = Console.ReadLine();
            if(hostName.Length == 0)
            {
                hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            }
            Connect(hostName, "hello");
        }

        static void Connect(string server, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                int port = 13000;
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);
                data = new byte[256];
                string responseData = string.Empty;
                int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket Error Code: {0}", e.SocketErrorCode.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

## Local Computer Example (*Successfull*)

I tried it only on my computer. First I opened *ServerTest* program then I ran *ClientText* program.

### Clientside Output

> Started...
>   İP Address:
>
> Sent hello
>   Received HELLO
>   Hit enter to continue

### Serverside Output

> Waiting for a connection...
>   Connected: 192.168.1.3:13000
>   Received: hello
>   Sent: HELLO
>   Waiting for a connection

## İnternet Network Example (*Unsuccessfull*)

I  tried with my friend whose ip address is "88.226.0.218". He learnt his ip address from [whatismyipaddress.com](http://whatismyipaddress.com/) I ran *ClientTest* program and he ran *ServerTest* program. Outputs are below:

### Clientside Output

> Started...
>   İP Address:
>   88.226.0.218
>   SocketErrorCode: ConnectionRefused
>   Hit enter to continue

### Serverside Output

> Waiting for a connection...

And nothing. *ServerTest* program only waits.

## My Possibility Considerations

- It can be using only İPv6 when I used *İPAddress.İPv6Any*
- My modem firewall can be preventing NatTraversal. If so, how can I enable modem's NatTraversal programatically?
- *AllowNatTraversal* method of *TcpListener* class, have come with .Net4, doesn't work properly. (I don't believe, but for the sake of possibility)

Any help would be appreciated. This is very much important for me. I have been delaying my project almost for a month due to not succeeding this failure.

Comment: You will most definitely need to configure your firewall to pass traffic arriving on the public-side port of your choice to the appropriate port on your workstation. Your friend is likely seeing the "Connection Refused" message because... your firewall is doing its job in refusing to pass packets arriving on that port number. How you do this will vary based on what particular firewall you have.

Comment: If we have to manually configure modem Nat, I prefer to use forwarded ports already in use. Is there available ports already forwarded?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your meaning when you say you prefer to use forwarded ports already in use. On your computer, you won't be able to bind your program to a port number already in use by another service; on the firewall, you won't be able to translate a port on the public interface to more than one port on the inside. While your firewall should be able to translate an arbitrary port number on the outside to an arbitrary port number on the inside, 1:1, it's not going to go 1:* or *:1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to try is a test between two computers on the same network. If that works, you can turn your attention away from **your** computer being the problem.

In any case, the culprit is very likely firewalls, as Christopher said. I would actually check your friend's firewall before your own, as some (most?) firewalls don't hinder outgoing connections.

In addition, if your friend is behind a router, you will need to have him forward port 13000 to his computer's local address (most likely 192.168.1.x) on port 13000.

More information (and guides!) on firewalls and port forwarding can be found here: http://portforward.com/help/start_here.htm