# how can I make a socket connection non-locally?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I tried to search for similar questions but I couldn't since I don't know how to pronounce this question.

My server codes for connection is...

```
server_Listener = new TcpListener(7778);
server_Listener.Start();


while (true)
{UserSocket user = new UserSocket();

    try
    {
        user.client = server_Listener.AcceptSocket();

    }
    catch
    {
        break;
    }

    if (user.client.Connected)
    {

        user.server_isClientOnline = true;
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate()
        {
            textBox1.AppendText("client connected\n");

        }));


        user.server_netStream = new NetworkStream(user.client);
```

the UserSocket class has a Socket(variable name client), and a netStream (server_netStream) to get to receive and send packet data from clients.

My Question is, this works just fine on local connections, but it doesn't work non-locally.

I tried to access to this server using my laptop, and my friend's, but non of them worked.

Not an error although... but it just couldn't receive the connection.

Are my codes wrong? or are there a new way of getting connection non-locally?

Comment: By 'non-locally' do you mean 'over the internet' or just some other computer within the same domain/workgroup?

Comment: Have you opened the port in the firewall of the server to allow other computers on the network access to your application?

Comment: would you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195421/connecting-sockets-over-internet-network-fails?rq=1

Comment: thanks a lot everybody. I used the term non-local as a connection between other computers over the internet. I'll look up more on port fowarding and firewall configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the firewall on your machine or some other issue on your network.  You might want to try Wireshark [(http://www.wireshark.org/](http://www.wireshark.org/)) and see if you can glean any information that way.

Comment: thanks a lot ..! the guys who commented on my questions also! I saw through those link and realized that I use a router, and didn't modify my firewall at all.. I still don't get what a Port forwarding is(though I know a easy way to do this), but maybe I'll run more tests.

Comment: Port forwarding is when a packet comes into your router or firewall destined for a specific IP and port combinations and the router or firewall forwards the packet to a different IP and or port on your internal network.

Comment: Still having some troubles on this issue. My server program listens to port 7778~7780. The port fowarding is provided by my router's configuration, and I can set a virtual ip(default is the computer which I'm accessing the configuration menu)'s internal ports to outer ports. I setted my ports 7778~7780 to the outer port 7778~7780 but it doesn't seem to work at all. Am i still miss understanding any concepts of port fowarding??

Comment: What brand of router do you have?  Could you send a screen print of the configuration (hide/obfuscate any IP's and other sensitive information).